# Is there a unicode character that is specifically not meant to be used normally, but instead only functions as a CSV separator?

Tags: csv, unicode

Is there a unicode character that is specifically not meant to be used normally, but instead only functions as a CSV separator? I know CSV stands for comma separated, but I use it here since it is the most common term for the concept I'm trying to ask about. Basically I would like to know whether there is a code point that was only added to unicode for the purpose of being used as a separator character between records in a text file.

Comment: If you're asking this because you want to use one character which you don't want to have to worry about escaping, that is by definition not possible. What if you would want to put the answer which tells you what character that is into your "CSV"… you'd have to encode that character as part of a value. So… just use a comma, because this snake will keep biting its tail into eternity.

Comment: But what about the separators between records? There's no reason those have to be new lines (however encoded). What about separators between record types? CSV isn't the only format, and not all formats encode just a single type of record, etc. Once you start down the slippery slope of putting *one* "special" separator in, you have to add all of the rest. Also, what decexe said.

Comment: Keeping in mind the disclaimers above, there are a number of Unicode code points that are explicitly meant to be not included in any text. So if you are sure that the raw contents of the CSV will never be shown, say, in a text editor or something, you can use those. http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html#noncharacters

Comment: Keep in mind that encoding and escaping are two different things. Your question is about "normally", but ... you never know, maybe someone will use your code point for other purposes, so I think you need to go to escaping (so a second layer). Note: some files in `/proc` use `00` as field separator [API mandates that such strings never contains zero].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 0x1C … 0x1F. They were specifically created for what you intend (and then standardised into ANSI_X3.4-1968 and later into Unicode).

[Summary from English Wikipedia](http://enwp.org/Record_separator):

> Can be used as delimiters to mark fields of data structures. If used for hierarchical levels, US is the lowest level (dividing plain-text data items), while RS, GS, and FS are of increasing level to divide groups made up of items of the level beneath it.

Comment: They were standardized for that purpose, but as far as I know they're not commonly used that way (I'd be interested in counterexamples). You can use 0x1F, for example, to separate fields, but if the fields contain binary data you might still need a way to represent a 0x1F byte within a field. If you're guaranteed that your data will contain no 0x1F bytes, that won't be an issue.